A little question about Webform Views Integration
Have set up the Webform module with Webform Views Integration. Created an additional view for webform submissions via cloning and alteration of 'Embed:Default', applied there a function from Views Aggregator Plus' armory to count the values in the fields. Then integrated that view into the submissions' table with considerable ease, gaining a dropdown that contains two views: default (Submissions) and custom (Quantity). How to switch them to get Quantity as default submissions' view?

Please update the post title to a one-line summary of the actual question or this post will not be useful on the site and may be closed.
